# Returning a Dictionary for an extra argument in python

Tags: python, arguments

I have a function that returns only a specific key from a nested dictionary of dictionaries that begins with "lv":

```
def kingdom (cats):


    for key, value in config_dict["animals"]["cats"].iteritems():
        if key.startswith('lv'):
            results.append(key)


    print results
```

This returns a only the keys in the nested dictionary of dictionaries that begin with "lv" when the user inputs "myprogram.py extract cats" in the command line.

However, I also want the user to get a more detailed view of the dictionary that's nested under "cats" that begin with "lv" by inputting something like "myprogram.py extract cats detailed" in the command line. How would I get it to print out the entire key, value pairs (ie the dictionary) under "cats" that begin with "lv"? And would I just put "detailed" as an argument?

Comment: Sounds like you have nested dictionaries and you need to iterate over them. Maybe try a recursive solution by putting your current code in a function that iterates over dictionary keys, and calls itself when the value is itself a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
def dict_key_starts_with(d, s='lv'):
    """Print keys that start with given value."""

    for k, v in d.items():
        try:
            if k.startswith(s):
                print(k)
        except AttributeError:
            pass

        if isinstance(v, dict):
            # nested dictionary, so run function again...
            dict_key_starts_with(v, s)


dict_key_starts_with(
    {'lv_foo': {'lv_bar': 123}, 'rex': 123}
)
```

The above prints:

```
lv_foo
lv_bar
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer each of your question:

> would I just put "detailed" as an argument?

Yes. Your function expression becomes

```
def extract(ctx, cats, detailed):
```

Where `detailed` is a boolean.

> How would I get it to print out the entire key, value pairs (ie the dictionary) under "cats" that begin with "lv"?

Something like this:

```
results = []

for i in config_dict['animals']['cats']:
    if i.startswith(ctx):
        res = [i]
        if detailed: desc.append(a[i])
        results.append(res)
```

Couple things:

- You don't need `iteritems()` to iterate through a dictionary. A simple `for...in` can give you both key and value.
- Results is now a list of lists whose format is [key, value(optional)].

Good luck!